# How to call a web page/service from different domain?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, cross-domain

I need to call a web page from different domain. When I call this page from browser, it responds normally. But when i call it from a server side code or from jquery ajax script, it responds empty xml.

I am trying to call a page or service like this:

http://www.otherdomain.com/oddsData.jsp?odds_flash_id=11&odds_s_type=1&odds_league=all&odds_period=all&me_select_string=&q=93801

this responds normally from browser. But when I write a c# code like this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "*/*";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip,deflate,sdch";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-US,en;q=0.8";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = "otherdomain.com";
var response = wc.DownloadString("http://www.otherdomain.com/oddsData.jsp?odds_flash_id=11&odds_s_type=1&odds_league=all&odds_period=all&me_select_string=&q=93801");
Response.Write(response);
```

i get empty xml as response:

```
<xml></xml>
```

**How can I get same response from server side code or client side which I got from browser?**

I tried solution here: [Calling Cross Domain WCF service using Jquery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java)

So that I didnt understand what to do, I couldnt apply solution described.

Comment: When I go to http://hititbet.com/oddsData.jsp?odds_flash_id=11&odds_s_type=1&odds_league=all&odds_period=all&me_select_string=&q=93801 in my browser, I get nothing. I'm betting you have to be logged in for this to work, which is why it isn't working for you from server-side code.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get same response from server side code or client side which I got from browser?

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction you cannot send cross domain AJAX requests from browsers.

From .NET on the other hand you could perfectly fine send this request. But probably the web server that you are trying to send the request to expects some HTTP headers such as the `User-Agent` header for example. So make sure that you have provided all the headers in your request that the server needs. For example to add the `User-Agent` header:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5";
    var response = wc.DownloadString("http://www.otherdomain.com/oddsData.jsp?odds_flash_id=11&odds_s_type=1&odds_league=all&odds_period=all&me_select_string=&q=93801");
    Response.Write(response);
}
```

You could use FireBug or Chrome developer toolbar to inspect all the HTTP request headers that your browser sends along the request that works and simply add those headers.

Comment: Did you look at the headers sent by your web browser? Did you send exactly the same? If you did it should work because the remote website has absolutely no way of distinguishing between the 2 requests.

Comment: Does the site require authentication? When I navigate to this link from my browser I get nothing so I suppose that you need to be authenticated in order to access it. So you need to send a valid authentication cookie along with the request.